# Difference between Unity's Renderer.sharedMaterial and Renderer.sharedMaterials

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript

What are the difference between **Renderer.sharedMaterial** and **Renderer.sharedMaterials** in Unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Renderer.sharedMaterial** returns first material used by a Renderer or null if Renderer has no materials. If there`re multiple materials, first one in that array will be returned.

**Renderer.sharedMaterials** returns all (1, 2, ...) materials used by a Renderer as array or null if Renderer has no materials.